# Perturbation in Besov space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

$\|f\|_{B^{0}_{p,p}}=(\sum_{j\geq -1} \|\Delta_j f\|_p^p)^{1/p}$ is the Besov norm of $f$.

Here the Fourier transform of $\Delta_jf~(j\geq 0)$ is $\psi(2^{-j}\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$ and $\psi$ is a smooth function with support in an annulus and $\hat{\Delta_{-1}f}(\xi)=\chi(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$. $$\chi(\xi)+\sum_{j\geq 0}\psi(2^{-j}\xi)=1.$$

Suppose there is a family of operator $\{K_{\sigma}\}_{\sigma\in \mathbb{M}^{d\times d}, ~~\|\sigma\|\leq 1}$ and we have $\|K_\sigma f\|_{B^0_{p,\infty}}\leq C \|f\|_{B^0_{p,\infty}}$ (C is independent with $\sigma$). Now suppose $\sigma(x): \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{M}^{d\times d}$ is continous, satisfying 
$$|\sigma(x)-\sigma(0)|\leq \epsilon_0,~~~~ \sigma(x)=\sigma(0) ~~~\forall |x|>\delta$$ 
where $\epsilon_0, \delta$ are small. Can we get
$$\|K_{\sigma(x)}f(x)-K_{\sigma(0)}f(x)\|_{B^0_{p,\infty}}\leq C(\epsilon_0)\|f\|_{B^0_{p,\infty}}~~~?$$

Comment: Is $K_\sigma$ supposed to be continuous in $\sigma$? Otherwise $K_{\sigma(x)}$ can translate $f(x)$ to $f(x+h(x))$, where $h$ is *any* function of $x$. In particular it can translate any garbage to a place arbitrarily close to $x$.